Can't port forward properly on QEMU/KVM libvirt

For TL;DR jump to the conclusion section

So I'm trying to ssh to a Windows 11 VM (running on QEMU via libvirt)
I've checked in several ways:

I've tried exposing and mapping the guest port and I've also checked on the host using netstat and it's true that the target port has a LISTENING state.

After trying to connect ssh while enabling verbose log, I saw it connected but after a few moments it disconnected, reason: connection reset by peer, from there I started to suspect it was blocked in the Windows firewall (the guest side) so I disabled all firewalls, but it was still the same (I checked the ssh log in Windows, there was no log that mentioned the ssh request, I guess the tcp packet didn't reach the guest?)

I tried using another non-admin port and it was the same (listen to port 8080 using ncat)


Commands used during the debugging process so far:

netstat -tulpn on the host to make sure the port is listening - output
ssh -vvv ryuu@localhost -p 4444 on the host to make sure it can connect or not - output
.\ncat.exe -k -v -l 8080 listen on non-admin port in Windows guest - output
ncat -v localhost 6969 to make sure can/cannot connect to guest - output

additional information:

content of sshd_config in Windows
sshd log
configuration of libvirt domain

as far as I understand from qemu-system-x86_64(1), the configuration forwards tcp packets sent to the listener on port 4444 and forwarded by qemu to the guest ip assigned via dhcp with port 22, is there something wrong with my understanding?
Previously I tried port forward too and it worked (the guest was Linux), but it didn't use libvirt and instead used the qemu command directly.
The conclusion
From all of these debugging processes, it just made me realize and convinced me that something was wrong with my libvirt domain configuration, but I'm not sure how to setup it properly, or it would be better if I could start Windows 11 without libvirt because I'm not familiar with libvirt, but tuning Windows 11 directly on qemu seems like a complicated process to me, and libvirt provides one-click solution that makes my life easier but, on the other hand, makes me feel lightheaded when something goes wrong.
I have tried following this guide to start Windows 11 directly with qemu:
sudo mkdir /tmp/emulated_tpm
sudo swtpm socket -d --tpmstate dir=/tmp/emulated_tpm/ --ctrl type=unixio,path=/tmp/emulated_tpm//swtpm-sock --log file=/tmp/win11-swtpm.log,level=20 --tpm2
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -machine pc-q35-9.0,accel=kvm \
  -cpu host,migratable=on \
  -smp 4,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1 \
  -m 8G \
  -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/win11.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-sata0-0-0,discard=unmap \
  -chardev socket,id=chrtpm,path=/tmp/emulated_tpm/swtpm-sock \
  -tpmdev emulator,id=tpm0,chardev=chrtpm \
  -device tpm-tis,tpmdev=tpm0 \
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,file=/usr/share/edk2/x64/OVMF_CODE.secboot.4m.fd,readonly=on \
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1,file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/win11_VARS.fd \
  -boot menu=on

but it can't boot and each time I tried to boot by pressing enter, it just refuse to boot without tell me the reason why it can't:

